# Finding GPS points on road segments

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gps

I have a set of road shapes (ROAD.zip) and lots of points which belong to a taxi in Beijing (txt files).
Each shape (segment) has a unique number.

I want to find the points on road segment and assign the segment number to the points.

ROAD.zip link :
https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/3573056

The ROAD shapes, has start x, end x, start y,end y. I believe these are the lat and long of start and end of road. Am I right?

Few points:

```
ID,NULL,NULL,Date,Lat,Long,Speed,Direction,Status
426242,4,0,20121101001700,116.3611526,39.6566734,0,138,1
426242,4,0,20121101001823,116.3611526,39.6566734,0,72,1
426242,4,0,20121101005759,116.3611526,39.6566925,0,72,1
426242,4,0,20121101010756,116.3611679,39.6567078,0,272,1
426242,4,0,20121101011735,116.3611298,39.6567192,0,272,1
426242,4,0,20121101011825,116.3611298,39.6567230,0,272,1
426242,4,0,20121101014539,116.3611298,39.6567192,0,168,1
426242,4,0,20121101014630,116.3611298,39.6567192,0,168,1
426242,4,0,20121101024857,116.3611145,39.6566887,0,72,1
426242,4,0,20121101024947,116.3611145,39.6566925,0,72,1
426242,4,0,20121101025040,116.3611145,39.6566925,0,72,1
426242,4,0,20121101025310,116.3611145,39.6567001,0,72,1
426242,4,0,20121101025651,116.3611298,39.6567001,0,72,1
```

Comment: This is typically done in a simple "spatial join" operation using a GIS (see this example: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html). You'll need to extract those road files out of their zip archive.

Comment: @PauloRaposo Thanks for the help. I checked it , I have Line (.shp) and points. I need to join the points that are on respective lines and get the ID of that line. I saw point and polygon in your link, but couldn't find tutorial on point and line. May you please help? Thank You

Comment: It's much the same fundamentally. Have a look at "Join Attributes By Location" in QGIS: https://trendct.org/2015/05/29/tutorial-how-to-merge-data-from-two-different-maps-using-qgis/. You'll just need to use a distance tolerance instead of geometric intersection to deal with your points being near but not on lines.